# How does Azure Backup Retention Work

Tags: azure, backup

I am trying to understand how Azure Backup retention works. Specifically related to retention policies and retain backup copies taken on. Azure does not seem to use standard backup terminology, for example full backup, incremental backup, and differential backup. But you can configure daily, weekly, monthly, and yearly retention policies. How exactly does this impact storage?

In this Azure Backup they have a topic on the impact of retention policy on storage and then fail to answer the question!

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/backup-azure-backup-faq/

> Q9. **If each recovery point is like a full point, does it impact the total billable backup storage?**  A9. Typical long-term retention point
>   products store backup data as full points. The full points are storage
>   inefficient but are easier and faster to restore. Incremental copies
>   are storage efficient but require you to restore a chain of data,
>   which impacts your recovery time. Azure Backup storage architecture
>   gives you the best of both worlds by optimally storing data for fast
>   restores and incurring low storage costs. This data storage approach
>   ensures that your ingress and egress bandwidth is used efficiently.
>   Both the amount of data storage and the time needed to recover the
>   data, is kept to a minimum.

Comment: Could you please elaborate which answers are unclear? That quote you mentioned does not look like the very retention-related, more like the clarification of relations between producing the full point backups and total billable storage.